dataframe tuple name column set a value
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [0,0]], index=['a', 'b'])
df.columns = [(1,2), (3,4)]
df.at['a', (1,2)] = 100
print(df)

My column name is a tuple and I want to set value 100 to one of rhe cell. The expected result is
   (1, 2)  (3, 4)
a     100       0
b       0       0

But I got
   (1, 2)  (3, 4)      1      2
a       0       0  100.0  100.0
b       0       0    NaN    NaN

Namely, pandas regards the tuple as two new columns. I also tried .loc and got the same result.
Actually it seems depend on the IDE, since in Jupternote, it is the first one. But in pycharm, it become the unexpected one.

Can you remove the df.columns= statement and try "df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [0,0]], index=['a', 'b'], columns=[(1,2), (3,4)])"

In VSCode it works as well. Interesting. Did you try other ways beside of at() e.g.: df['a'][(1, 2)] = 100? Or maybe using the reference to the column e.g.: df.at['a', df.columns[0]] = 100

I guess the difference is the pandas version. You can print pd.__version__ in both IDEs and compare.

@MichaelButscher you are right, it is purely because of the pandas version.

Your code should work fine with at since this selector is designed to access a single value. Versions 1.0.3, 1.4.3, 1.5.3, and 2.1.4 all assign the value correctly.
The issue occurs with df.loc['a', (1,2)] = 100, which assigns to your single cell with pandas 1.0.3 but broadcasts to new columns for all the other versions.
To avoid ambiguity, you should wrap the tuple in a list:
df.loc['a', [(1,2)]] = 100

Output:
   (1, 2)  (3, 4)
a     100       0
b       0       0

If you want to compare different pandas version, try:
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [0,0]], index=['a', 'b'])
df.columns = [(1,2), (3,4)]
df.at['a', (1,2)] = 100
print("df.at['a', (1,2)] = 100")
print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [0,0]], index=['a', 'b'])
df.columns = [(1,2), (3,4)]
df.loc['a', (1,2)] = 100
print("df.loc['a', (1,2)] = 100")
print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0], [0,0]], index=['a', 'b'])
df.columns = [(1,2), (3,4)]
df.loc['a', [(1,2)]] = 100
print("df.loc['a', [(1,2)]] = 100")
print(df)

